# how to stop sound, control volume... with AudioToolbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How i do the following using the AudioToolbox framework instead of the AVFoundation

```
playing
stop
setCurrentTime
volume
```

i implement the SoundEffect class from the BubbleLevel example code and this options don't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the AudioQueue functionality, it doesn't match the AVFoundations methods exactly, but is similar.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html

Controlling Audio Queues

```
* AudioQueueStart
* AudioQueuePrime
* AudioQueueFlush
* AudioQueueStop
* AudioQueuePause
* AudioQueueReset
```